# Como actualizar un progress bar en windows forms .NET Framework 4.6.1 sin que se congele la UI utilizando asyn/await

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola estoy intentando simular el avance de una tarea con async/await en un ProgressBar. Ya he intentado de todo , con el método Invoke, con el BeginInvoke , con el Action, con el SincronizationContext y ninguno funciona. Todos me estan congelando la interfaz. A continuación adjunto el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static ProgressBar progressBar1;

        public Form1()
        {
           

            InitializeComponent();


            progressBar1 = new ProgressBar();
            progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 197);
            progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
            progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(736, 23);
            progressBar1.TabIndex = 4;


            this.Controls.Add(progressBar1);

            progressBar1.Maximum = 1000000;

           
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           await  tarea();

        }

        public async Task tarea()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
               
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("segundo plano" + i);
                    UpdateUI(i);
                }
             });
        }


        public void UpdateUI(int i)
        {
           this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { progressBar1.Value= i; }));
         
            //progressBar1.Value = i;

        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //aumentar value
            Class2 class2 = new Class2();

            class2.valor();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



    }
}
```

Pensé que era por el static del progress bar pero ya intente con uno de los Buttons actualizar el Text pero lo mismo se queda congelada la interfaz. Que es lo que esta pasando? Lo que he podido ver es que si yo le quito el BeginInvoke ya sea al Form o al progress directamente y solo ejecuto el Debug.WriteLine() entonces si que se ejecuta en segundo plano y no me congela la UI pero cuando le pongo el Invoke porque es la única manera de actualizar la UI entonces si actualiza el progress pero se congela el Form.

Comment: Usa la clase Thread

Comment: @Japv Con la clase Thread posiblemente funcione pero porque con la async /await no funciona? Debería funcionar con async/await si se supone que el Task.Run() se ejecuta en otro thread o me equivoco?